# Send log messages to remote API

Tags: logging

Is there a quick and easy way to send logging messages somewhere to remote? We have a major issue in our Android app that reproduces only on customer's device. We have no remote logging tool integrated in the app and need some very fast way to send *trace* logs somewhere to have an ability to view them after the bug reproduces.
Would be perfect to have some kind of remote server receiving HTTP requests like: http://log.com/msg=log_message and putting all the messages in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

You can send sms message on your phone (or on your email address) by some service, what send sms on your phone and email by API (sms.ru for example)